# Response.Redirect not working

Tags: asp.net

I am not sure why this is not working.

I am verifying the logged on person has the correct security, if they do not I want to redirect them to another page.

If they do have the correct security the rest of the code on the page will continue to execute.

When I step through the code, it does execute the response.redirect, but the page continues to load.

```
strSQL = "Select * from tblSecurity Where SFID = '" & Right(My.User.Name, 4) & "' and (SecurityLevel = '900' or SecurityLevel = '850')"
ds = objData.SQLExecuteDataset(strSQL, CommandType.Text)
If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
    Response.Redirect("~/NotAuthorized.aspx", False)
End If
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Use `true` on the parameter, and return from the function (do not continue with the rest code)

Comment: @Mike So you have debugged and and verified that `ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0`?

Comment: I don't, since there is no way for the user to access the sql code.  It exists in the code behind and runs on the page load.

Comment: I understand the concern, I did not explain it completly.  In my company a user is given a unique alphanumberic id. The Right(My.User.Name, 4) returns that ID.  That protects me from someone using a sql command as a name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's exactly what you told it to do.

Passing `false` as the [second parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx#parameters) makes it not terminate the current page.

Comment: Since the redirect is in a try catch block, I throw an error if I don't add the false second parameter.

Comment: @Mike This is normal to get this throw, so use a flag, move out of the try/catch block, and make there the redirect with true.

Comment: @Mike: Or just ignore `ThreadAbortException`s.  Or pass false, call `CompleteRequest()`, and return.  (see remarks)

Answer (score 0):

dont give the table value equal to zero...give the validation like ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0... it means the table is holding the record if the given login details are right.

Comment: `If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then` is easier to look at than wrapping all your code in an `If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then`. You can clearly see with his method the user is meant to be redirected if the details aren't found.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all this and more ... and I only note my solution here for posterity and my own reference later. I ran into this problem while I had about 6 VS projects open, each in their own VS instance. Once I closed all but the one project down the problem went away. I am not sure what it was about the other project(s) that caused this particular problem but apparently VS doesn't like having too many of itself open.